# How to fix null value error when loading configuration file

Tags: spring-boot, configuration-files

Spring Boot throws `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null` when auto-configuring a component.  I have no `null` properties in my `application.properties` file.  Its a mystery.

I have tried a bit of everything.  The error message indicates the problem is with the factory.core property in the file.  I tried removing it, but I get a more generic error.  If I put the factory.core back, then error complains about it specifically.

My application.properties has these four:

```
factory.protocol=http
factory.host=localhost
factory.core=recommend
factory.port=8983
```

I have these annotations

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("factory")
```

My code has only the setters and getters for these fields.

```
private String protocol;
private String host;
private int port;
private String core;
```

Spring Boot writes this out.

```
Description:

    Failed to bind properties under 'factory' to com.ot.cem.recommender.engine.ClientFactory$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1530d0ff:

        Property: factory.core
        Value: recommend
        Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:4:14
        Reason: Failed to bind properties under 'factory' to com.ot.cem.recommender.engine.ClientFactory$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1530d0ff

Action:

Update your application's configuration
The exception is
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Bindable.box(Bindable.java:255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Bindable.of(Bindable.java:248) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need @Configuration and @ConfigurationProperties . Try removing @Configuration.
Some useful links : [link1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12901) and [link2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the configuration annotation processor in your dependencies?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

See  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor

Either that or Spring really cannot find your `application.properties` file. You could also test by annotating each field, e.g. `@Value("factory.prototype")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies.  I tried removing @Configuration, but same result.  link2 had good explanation between the two annotations.  I forgot to state in my original post, I also have the @Component annotation set because I autowire the class I am trying to configure in another class.

I use Gradle, so I have
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.0.6.RELEASE").  I read the docs link.  I think Spring finds application.properties OK because the error mentions one of the properties.  In my case factory.core.

Not sure what to do.  As far as what I can determine, it should work.